# One footprint, two configurations - KiCad

Tags: kicad, symbol, footprint

I want to make a single PCB that works for two product versions.

One of the footprints will have to sport different placements of the same component for the different versions. I want a footprint with 3 holes. In it, I want to place a component with only two pins. With the first version it should be aligned to the right, and in the second to the left.

How could I accomplish this in KiCad?

Thanks

(I am using v6 now, but could go v7 as well)

[image: doodle]

Comment: Can you just make it 4 pins (on two separate footprints) and use the usual variants mechanism? What kind of component is it? A resistor, a pin header, or something more exotic?

Comment: Nope, no space.

Comment: Will the assembly be done in-house, or at a contractor/vendor? Will the part be machine-placed or hand-placed?

Comment: Mass-manufactured by 3rd party with pick n place.

Comment: I see that I missed part of your first comment. This is a cable socket, not very exotic :) Thanks for input!

Answer (score 3):

Just make a footprint with three holes, and specify the placement in a note or detail on the assembly drawing.

A mark or comment in silkscreen may be helpful for post-assembly inspection. Even just a "*" to draw attention to the location as a possible point of error.

Answer (score 0):

Make two footprints with two holes each. Place them such that one pin overlaps on the exact same coordinate. Use DNF for one of the two components. Ignore/modify the footprint to handle DRC warnings.

Comment: My board house liked this option the most so I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have two different PCB assemblies to assemble, monitor, stock, and release to production or sales, consider making a single PCB assembly but use a 3 pin socket.

You would then make the version/model differentiation only when creating or installing the cable assembly.

One cable version will be a 2-wire assembly with an unused pin at the left, the other cable assembly will be similar but with an unused pin on the right. Ideally this would require that the cable socket be a polarized type. However, if this is an un-polarized socket and you can control the process carefully you may get away with only having to rotate the cable between versions. Instructions for selecting the required cable orientation could be silk-screened onto the PCB.

The production of a wired cable assembly and it's insertion is often more of a manual operation so making the version decision there should be simple and easy to correct in case of an error. If there were an error made you just need to swap-out or reverse the cable, (as compared to potentially reworking a soldered in place socket on the PCB assembly). The PCB and/or PCB assembly might then be fully compatible for both versions of the finished product.

The above is assuming that the rest of the two PCB assembly versions are identical. But even if this is not the case using a common 3-pin socket could still reduce potential errors at assembly.

Comment: Thanks! Your idea is good in the general case. Unfortunately I don't think there are 3 pin sockets that mate with my male header of the cable. And that one comes from a 3rd party. It would also somewhat defeat the purpose in this particular case since one of the reasons for doing this is related to which pins that are exposed to air after potting the pcb. If the socket har 3 pins, all are always exposed.

Comment: @Alexander Ohm - Well that does start to sound a bit exotic. The new requirements do put limitations on your options, not to mention the need for potting the PCB. Though even with the original concept it seems that at least 2 pins would be exposed prior to adding on the male header.